# Locust + docker run with image old version doesn't work

Tags: docker, locust

I run

```
docker run -p 8089:8089 -v ${PWD}:/locust locustio/locust:0.14.6  -f /locust/short.py
```

and it displays an error message like a photo below

[image]

But when I run with a new version

```
docker run -p 8089:8089 -v ${PWD}:/locust locustio/locust  -f /locust/short.py
```

It works successfully

Answer (score 0):

Both are tag has different entrypoint.

- [latest](https://hub.docker.com/layers/locustio/locust/latest/images/sha256-f1b8cdd8a8393c25fac305a1bc3cbfe72e5f3fa8de4d0d267acc71bb956468b5?context=explore)
- [0.14.6](https://hub.docker.com/layers/locustio/locust/0.14.6/images/sha256-d55909ed729d8e104be4ed223409218355ec2c13dd8ba0c0c3c3f6499ea60532?context=explore)

It **latest** the command work because the `entrypoint` is `locust`, so when you when run

```
locustio/locust  -f /locust/short.py
```

it will be process like

```
 locust -f locustfile.py
```

So this the valid command for `locust` and it should work.

In another case for **locustio/locust:0.14.6** there is no entrypoint but only has `CMD`

```
CMD ["./docker_start.sh"]
```

so the docker run command  `-f /locust/short.py` will not work, as it not executable.

You can try below command might it work

```
docker run -p 8089:8089 -v ${PWD}:/locust locustio/locust:0.14.6 "locust -f /locust/short.py"
```

Comment: I run as you said but it still an error: 
PS E:\locust> docker run -p 8089:8089 -v ${PWD}:/locust locustio/locust:0.14.6 "locust -f /locust/short.py"         
c:\program files\docker\docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"locust -f /locust/short.py\": stat locust -f /locust/short.py: no such file or directory": unknown.